# How to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss.ms when getting difference between 2 times

Tags: awk, perl, aix, printf

I performed a calculation that converts current timestamp giving milliseconds as well using perl command such as below:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=time -MPOSIX=strftime -e '
$now = int(time() * 1000);
printf "%s.%03d\n", strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime(int($now/1000))), ($now % 1000);'
```

From the above I want to convert the output to seconds, which I can achive using below for example:

```
echo "21:48:40.596" | awk -F: '{ if (NF == 1) {print $NF} else if (NF == 2) {print $1 * 60 + $2} else if (NF==3) {OFMT = "%2.3f"; print $1 * 3600 + $2 * 60 + $3 } }'
```

With the commands above if I compare to readings in seconds apart, I can use the command below to get the difference between the 2 values in seconds with maintaining the milliconds:

EXAMPLE:

```
DIFF_SEC=$(echo "78522.896 - 78520.596" | bc -l | awk '{printf("%.3f\n", $1)}')
```

OUTPUT:

```
echo $DIFF_SEC
2.300
```

I would like to know from the above how can I calculate the difference between the command above in hh:mm:ss.milseconds

I have managed to figure out the below, however milliseconds is not showing:

```
DIFF=`printf '%02dh:%02dm:%02ds.%03d\n' $((DIFF_SEC/3600)) $((DIFF_SEC%3600/60)) $((DIFF_SEC%60))`
```

OUTPUT:

```
echo "$DIFF"
00h:00m:02s.000
```

What I am expecting is below:

```
00h:00m:02s.300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Time::HiRes ('gettimeofday','tv_interval')

my @t1 = Time::HiRes::gettimeofday();
# do a bunch of stuff
my $t2 = Time::HiRes::tv_interval(\@t1,[Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()]);
say $t2;
```

0.040614

That's an example, start with 'now', then take difference between first 'now' and second 'now'. I think this is what you are asking unless I'm reading you wrong.

You are passing tv_interval an array reference of the first time array, and an array reference of the second now time array.

You basically didn't use Time::HiRes fully, it does all this already natively, so there was no need to use anything else. This is very useful for logging etc.

If you struggle using perl on AIX you can use the below, which is not ideal, but it does work:

```
t1=`perl -MTime::HiRes=time  -e 'print time'`
sleep 1
t2=`perl -MTime::HiRes=time  -e 'print time'`
DIFF_SEC=`echo $t2-$t1|bc -l | awk '{printf("%.3f\n", $1)}'`
echo "$DIFF_SEC\n"
MS=`echo "$DIFF_SEC"| awk -F'.' '{print $2}'`
DIFF=`printf '%02d:%02d:%02d\n' $((DIFF_SEC/3600)) $((DIFF_SEC%3600/60)) $((DIFF_SEC%60))`
DIFF2=`printf '%02d hrs %02d mins %02d\n' $((DIFF_SEC/3600)) $((DIFF_SEC%3600/60)) $((DIFF_SEC%60))`
echo "$DIFF" | awk '{print $1"'".$MS"'"}'
echo "$DIFF2" | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 "'".$MS"' Secs"}'
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.017

00:00:01.017
00 hrs 00 mins 01.017 Secs
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick reminder that we can use the command `date` to reformat dates and times

```
$ DIFF_sec=91.034    ## calculate diff in your favorite way
$ date -d "0+$DIFF_sec seconds"  '+%H:%M:%S.%3N'
00:01:31.034
```

`date` can also calculate differentes

```
$ T1=95.1
$ T2=195.2
$ date -d "0 + $T2 seconds - $T1 seconds"  '+%H:%M:%S.%3N'
00:01:40.100
```

Finally, T1 and T2 can be calculated by date:

```
$ start=`date '+%s.%3N'`
$ end=`date '+%s.%3N'`
$ date -d " 0 + $end seconds - $start seconds"  '+%H:%M:%S.%3N'
00:00:05.706
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Time::HiRes, use Time::Format:

```
perl -MTime::Format -e 'print $time{"hh:mm:ss.mmm"}'
```

The `Time::HiRes` would make sense if your whole process is inside the `perl`. There is very limited set of tasks where you need to measure time up to nanosecond.

But since you are using command-line execution, I assume you want to measure some execution of some tools - you would loose nanoseconds on the execution process alone and, if milliseconds is enough, you do not need nanoseconds - the Time::Format is enough.

And if you need to measure a time difference, you can do something like:

```
#/bin/bash 
t1=`perl -MTime::HiRes=time  -e 'print time'`
sleep 1
t2=`perl -MTime::HiRes=time  -e 'print time'`
diff=`echo $t2-$t1|bc`
echo $t1, $t2, $diff
perl -MTime::Format -e "print time_format 'mm:ss.mmm', $diff"
```

Comment: For some reason using perl I get missing dependencies on AIX that requires for your logic to work, which is a problem

Comment: use `cpan`. It will install missing dependencies into your personal library. Or with `sudo` - system-wide. Or talk with your sysadmins.